# Show a Component only once and never again VUEJS (current session)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Code is in: VueJS

Hi,

I'm curious how to show a component once and then never again. I've tried `v-if` and `v-model` but none of them seem to work. 
This is my code:

```
<template  >

    <div id="fakeLoader" v-if="show"></div>
</template>

<script>
import $ from 'jquery'
import '../../bower_components/fakeLoader/fakeLoader.min'

export default {
  name: 'Fakeloader',
  data() {
    return {
      show: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showLoader() {
      this.show = false;
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      // Init Fakeloader
      $('#fakeLoader').fakeLoader({
        timeToHide: 800,
        spinner: 'spinner5',
        bgColor: '#274156'
      }
    );
    });
    this.showLoader();
  }
}
</script>

<style>
  @import '../../bower_components/fakeLoader/fakeLoader.css';

  #fakeLoader {
    z-index: 999999 !important;
  }
</style>
```

I'm setting a boolean called `show` and make it false whenever the jQuery function is called and make it permanently false so this component will not show again FOR THE CURRENT SESSION. So if the user opens another tab, the fakeloader should appear again at the beginning.

Comment: When you say never again do you mean in this session or do you literally mean never again for this user?

Comment: Sorry, I mean for the current session. So Like I'm trying to implement a fake loader and it'll only appear when a user lands on the page. However I'm using routing so if I go to another page and go back to the home page, the fake loader will appear again. I don't want that to happen. I just want the loader to appear when a user land on the page. If the users opens the site on another tab, he or she should get the fakeloader again

Comment: Use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Comment: I really don't think I have to use sessionStorage as it's an overkill. I believe it's just a boolean and once it's activated, it'll be turned off and therefore won't appear again

Comment: It looks like your `show` variable is inside the component you're trying to control? It needs to be outside the component, so that it exists and can be tested before the component is shown.

Comment: Okay that would make sense. So would I initialize that show variable in main vue component?

Comment: I've already replicate this issue, try to use `mounted()` life cycle hooks of VueJS. you can see here https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

Comment: @john, could you elaborate more? I've already used mounted() in the original problem

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [v-cloak](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak). It allows you to segment areas of your site based on whether vue is loaded or not.

For your example, I'd have a CSS sheet comprised of

```
#app[v-cloak] {
    display: none
}

#fakeloader {
    display: none
}

#fakeloader[v-cloak] {
    display: block
}
```

Then

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="fakeloader" v-cloak>
    This is my loader
  </div>
  <div id="content" v-cloak>
    This is my page
  </div>
</div>
```

This will let your app have preference when vue is loaded and the loader having preference when vue is loading.

EDIT: Just to show why a fiddle is a good thing to have before you answer. I have a [fiddle up here](https://jsfiddle.net/335854tf/) which should demonstrate and I fixed the code.